# How to change an user password with SQL on SuiteCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Previously in SugarCRM, the following statement was enough:

```
UPDATE users SET user_hash = MD5('PASSWORD') WHERE user_name = 'USERNAME';
```

I can't find a single site on how to do it now with SuiteCRM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this:

> Can I still use MD5 passwords? I’m used to that and can easily administer passwords in the database using just MD5.
>
> Sugar will still recognize passwords stored in MD5 format, but anytime a password is changed it will convert to the newer format. Unless very old PHP build (5.2) used in a system where better
> crypt() is not available, new password will use salted hashing algorithm.

Posted it on SugarCRM's site:

https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2012/05/16/new-for-sugar-6-5-stronger-password-storage-encryption/

It turns out that SuiteCRM uses this new password format too, but, as well, it still recognizes md5 passwords, so, same sql statement works:

```
UPDATE users SET user_hash = MD5('PASSWORD') WHERE user_name = 'USERNAME';
```

I did it and it works :)

Btw, same post recommends change passwords with PHP crypt like this:

```
crypt(md5("newpassword"))
```

Maybe it can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

For SuiteCRM 8.4.2

It uses

```
password_hash(strtolower(md5('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT))
```

you can hash the pass with php before.
May it helps someone